# Android Draw only highlighted region on Canvas

Tags: java, android, graphics, canvas

I have a drawing on a canvas and I want to select only particular region that is surrounded by a line with different color (Something like the magic wand tool in Photoshop or the Fuzzy Select tool in GIMP).

Is there a way to do this and how to make it possible to paint only this region?

Thanks